Why does the projection-motion of the moon on the earth's surface have the shape of a sinusoid?
Why does the projection-motion of the moon on the earth's surface have the shape of a sinusoid? How does this fit with the tellurium model?


It's mostly perspective distortion.  E.g. if you draw a straight line around a ball, then tilt it, the line appears curved.  If you were to view this map from the Moon's perspective, it would largely be a straight line.   There is also some map distortion, and the Earth rotation also playing a minor role.

Please give proper attribution for any images you post on Stack Exchange, unless they're your own work. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325015/334566

@PM 2Ring  there's a logo on the bottom left, isn't it enough?

You can get an idea for what I referred to above using this 3D rendering of the path.  Align the edges of the partial eclipse with the edge of the visible globe and the line is much straighter than if it goes through the center of the screen. https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/globe/2028-july-22
